# PhoneAuth Firebase: Update Phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented firebase phone auth to verify phone number in my project and its working fine for me, But not able to update phone number. Like if a user had logged in with phone number A and now he wants to update this to phone number B. How will it be solved?

Comment: Amit, if a user wants to **change their phone number** actually **in Firebase authentication**  - this exists in Firebase:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#updatePhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer where you log in with your email account and update the mobile number into the same account. You may use the solution to log in with phone and update the phone number into the same account and see if it works. Anyway I will be working on this exact solution down in my project and update the answer then. But until then you can try to see if this works. Follow the regular firebase phone auth procedure as given here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
  if let error = error {
    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
    return
  }
  // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
  // ...
}

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
    withVerificationID: verificationID,
    verificationCode: verificationCode)
```

**Then do not use the following code**

```
// Sign In The User
Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { _, error in

}
```

**But use this code**

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { _, error in

    if error == nil {
        print("Whopdee doo")

    } else {
        print("Aargh!!!")
    }
})
```