# Update Phone Number in Firebase Authentication - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to update the phone number in firebase `auth?` The thing is if the user entered a wrong number in registration then can I update the old number to new one then send the verification code in that new number? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please see my answer here it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783048/3904109

Answer (score 4):

There is a [method on the `User` object called `updatePhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#updatephonenumber_:completion:), which seems to be what you want.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about what this does to the verification status, although I'd assume it indeed will require the new number to be verified too. Give it a try, and let me know if that isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

On the screen where the user has to enter their phone number:

```
var verificationId: String?

PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

    if let error = error { return }

    self.verificationId = verificationID else { return }
}
```

On the screen where the user has to enter the sms verification code:

```
guard let safeVerificationId = self.verificationId else { return }

let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: safeVerificationId, verificationCode: smsTextField.text!)

Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePhoneNumber(credential, completion: { (error) in

    if let error = error { return }
})
```

Comment: This worked for me and should deffo be marked as the correct answer. Followed a few other solutions around the web and they were all bobbins. Firebase documentation was rubbish too. Thank you @lanceSamaria

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePhoneNumber(credential, completion: { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("succes")
            }
        })
```